# How do I extract the indexes from my GAE server

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to reteive the indexes, i am able to get `datastore-indexes.xml` but that doesn't contain the auto generated indexes.

I used the following command to download my app. and I the indexes in `index.yaml` but it is not in xml.

```
./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

Is it possible to get all the indexes in xml?

Answer (score 0):

Auto generated indexes are in WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml.
Here is explanation: 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#Java_Using_automatic_index_configuration